# how to import csv file to cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I wanted to import csv file to cassandra so, first I created keyspace and columnfamily like this

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY Consumer_complaints(
    Date_received varchar,
    Product varchar,
    Sub_product varchar,
    Issue varchar,
    Sub_issue varchar,
    Consumer_complaint_narrative varchar,
    Company_public_response varchar,
    Company varchar,
    State varchar,
    ZIP_code varint,
    Tags varchar,
    Consumer_consent_provided varchar,
    Submitted_via varchar,
    Date_sent_to_company varchar,
    Company_response_to_consumer varchar,
    Timely_response varchar,
    Consumer_disputed varchar,
    Complaint_ID varint,
    PRIMARY KEY(Complaint_ID)
);
```

I got a csv file from www.data.gov called consumer complaints
and then I typed the command line

```
COPY consumer_complaints (Date_received,Product,Sub_product, Issue, Sub_issue, Consumer_complaint_narrative, Company_public_response, Company, State, ZIP_code, Tags, Consumer_consent_provided, Submitted_via, Date_sent_to_company, Company_response_to_consumer, Timely_response, Consumer_disputed, Complaint_ID) FROM 'consumer_complaints.csv';
```

Sample Input

```
3/21/2017,Credit reporting,,Incorrect information on credit report,Information is not mine,,Company has responded to the consumer and the CFPB and chooses not to provide a public response,EXPERIAN DELAWARE GP,TX,77075,Older American,N/A,Phone,03/21/2017,Closed with non-monetary relief,Yes,No,2397100
04/19/2017,Debt collection,"Other (i.e. phone, health club, etc.)",Disclosure verification of debt,Not disclosed as an attempt to collect,,,"Security Credit Services, LLC",IL,60643,,,Web,04/20/2017,Closed with explanation,Yes,No,2441777
```

Error

```
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 797XX : invalid lit for int() with base 10: '797XX',  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 354XX : invalid lit for int() with base 10: '354XX',  given up without retries
Failed to import 2 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 313XX : invalid lit for int() with base 10: '313XX',  given up without retries
Failed to import 2 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 054XX : invalid lit for int() with base 10: '054XX',  given up without retries
```

how can I fix it??

Comment: Show your sample csv file

Comment: Hey @ImJa which cassandra version's cqlsh are you using ? I have used cassandra 2.2.4's cqlsh and it working properly

Comment: I Check the data, some of the zip code  has non integer value like `797XX`, `354XX`,  `313XX` and `054XX`. You can see that it's clearly not integer. You either change these value to integer or alter your table and change the type of your ZIP_code to 'varchar'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra doesn't preserve the order of column when creating.
You need to specify the column name when importing data.

Try this command :

```
COPY consumer_complaints (Date_received,Product,Sub_product, Issue, Sub_issue, Consumer_complaint_narrative, Company_public_response, Company, State, ZIP_code, Tags, Consumer_consent_provided, Submitted_via, Date_sent_to_company, Company_response_to_consumer, Timely_response, Consumer_disputed, Complaint_ID) FROM 'c.csv' WITH HEADER = true;
```

Sample Input :

```
Date_received,Product,Sub_product, Issue, Sub_issue, Consumer_complaint_narrative, Company_public_response, Company, State, ZIP_code, Tags, Consumer_consent_provided, Submitted_via, Date_sent_to_company, Company_response_to_consumer, Timely_response, Consumer_disputed, Complaint_ID
07/26/2013,Mortgage,FHA mortgage,"Loan servicing, payments, escrow account",,,,"CITIBANK, N.A.",NC,28056,,N/A,Web,07/29/2013,Closed with explanation,Yes,No,467750
09/26/2014,Consumer Loan,Vehicle loan,Managing the loan or lease,,,,HSBC NORTH AMERICA HOLDINGS INC.,NY,12572,,N/A,Web,09/26/2014,Closed with explanation,Yes,No,1046323
```

Output :

```
complaint_id  | company                          | company_public_response | company_response_to_consumer | consumer_complaint_narrative | consumer_consent_provided | consumer_disputed | date_received | date_sent_to_company | issue                                    | product       | state | sub_issue | sub_product  | submitted_via | tags | timely_response | zip_code
--------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+--------------+---------------+------+-----------------+----------
      1046323 | HSBC NORTH AMERICA HOLDINGS INC. |                    null |      Closed with explanation |                         null |                       N/A |                No |    09/26/2014 |           09/26/2014 |               Managing the loan or lease | Consumer Loan |    NY |      null | Vehicle loan |           Web | null |             Yes |    12572
       467750 |                   CITIBANK, N.A. |                    null |      Closed with explanation |                         null |                       N/A |                No |    07/26/2013 |           07/29/2013 | Loan servicing, payments, escrow account |      Mortgage |    NC |      null | FHA mortgage |           Web | null |             Yes |    28056
```

**Edited**

I checked the data from https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database, some of the zip code has non-integer values like `797XX`, `354XX`,  `313XX` and `054XX`. You can see that it's clearly not integer. You can either change these value to integer or alter your table and change the type of your ZIP_code field to `varchar`

Comment: I tried your command. but error still exist like this : Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 797XX : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '797XX',  given up without retries

Comment: @ImJa it should work. Check my input and output. And also show your input for which its not working

Comment: it's a original csv file part of header-Date received,Product,Sub-product,Issue,Sub-issue,Consumer complaint n       arrative,Company public response,Company,State,ZIP code,Tags,Consumer        consent provided?,Submitted via,Date sent to company,Company response        to consumer,Timely response?,Consumer disputed?,Complaint ID
as you can see, there is blanks in column so I fixed it. I think It's a reason why error is generated. if It's true, How should I do?

Comment: Change the header or remove it. If you remove also remove `WITH HEADER = true` part from the copy command

Comment: I removed a part of header and WITH HEADER = true, but It isn't working.

Comment: I think this csv file is not proper to import in Cassandra. there are a lot of exceptions like zipcode. I've tried a several times but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says:

> Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 11/08/2013 : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11/08/2013', given up without retries

It looks like Cassandra is trying to insert the date string as an integer. Without seeing the CSV, I'd guess that the columns aren't in the right order and the date is being parsed as one of your varint fields. If you share a sample of the CSV it might be easier to help debug.

Comment: You can download csv file from https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database. I don't kknow why Cassandra tried to insert the data string as integer.

Comment: It's a sample:::::::::::03/21/2017,Credit reporting,,Incorrect information on credit report,In       formation is not mine,,Company has responded to the consumer and the C       FPB and chooses not to provide a public response,EXPERIAN DELAWARE GP,       TX,77075,Older American,N/A,Phone,03/21/2017,Closed with non-monetary        relief,Yes,No,2397100